# getting data from an object's array with vue.js

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js

I am trying to access the following data in Vue.js

```
{"id":1,"name":"Westbrook","created_at":"2017-06-10T16:03:07.336Z","updated_at":"2017-06-10T16:03:07.336Z","stats":[{"id":1,"player_id":1,"points":2558,"assists":840,"rebounds":864,"created_at":"2017-06-10T16:03:07.373Z","updated_at":"2017-06-10T16:03:07.373Z"}]}
```

`self.player = response.name` works. now i need `self.point`

```
methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      var self = this;
      $.get("api/v1/players/1", function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        self.player = response.name;
        self.point = response.stats.points 
      });
    }
  }
```

I have thus far tried `response.stats["points"]`, `response.stats[2]`, `response.stats[ { points } ]`, `response.stats[points]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `stats` property in your json holds an array in which the first object has a property named `points`

So use `response.stats[0].points`

---

*Keep in mind though that the `stats` is probably an array for a reason. It might hold more than one objects in the future, so always using the first element `[0]` might not be a valid approach*.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can help you

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
json.stats[0].points
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
response = {"id":1,"name":"Westbrook","created_at":"2017-06-10T16:03:07.336Z","updated_at":"2017-06-10T16:03:07.336Z","stats":[{"id":1,"player_id":1,"points":2558,"assists":840,"rebounds":864,"created_at":"2017-06-10T16:03:07.373Z","updated_at":"2017-06-10T16:03:07.373Z"}]}
```

If you want to access the name

```
console.log(response.name) // Westbrook
```

If you want to access the stats data which contain list, simply target

```
let stats=response.stats[0] //By getting the first index in the list
```

Get the points in stats

```
console.log(stats.points) // 2588
```